# Reading all kinds of information from the blockchain

Tags: solana-program, account-data

(For a project of mine which is a full Solana blockchain "status" tracker. For public!)

**Problem: Reading Pair/Pool info**

1. How do I even get the info which pairs exist without looping through all?
2. How do I interpret the data of the "token" accounts... Since normal accounts don´t hold non-native token but just have authority over a token account.
3. When AMM are being used. Is this also in the DATA? Especially how the AMM works?

GREAT THANKS!
in advance :)